# Trouble with navbar element hover

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav

When I hover over the individual links, the part that changes color doesn't reach all the way up. I feel like there is a better/more efficient way to do this then what I am doing right now. If anyone can help that would be great!

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-blue">
    <li><a href="" class="nav-hdr">Nigel Silva</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="el-b-1">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="el-b-2">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="el-b-3">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="el-b-4">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="el-b-5">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-hdr {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  left: -27%;
  top: 5%;
}
.nav{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0;
  text-align:right;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 55px;
}
.nav li{
  display:inline;
}
.nav a{
  display:inline-block;
  padding-right:15px;
  color: #000;
  margin-top: auto;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
.nav a:hover, .nav a:focus {
  color: #FFF;  
}
.nav-blue {
  background-color: #00aeef;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.nav-blue a {
  color: #FFF;
}
.el-b-1:hover, .el-b-1:focus, .el-b-2:hover, .el-b-2:focus, .el-b-3:hover, .el-b-3:focus,
.el-b-4:hover, .el-b-4:focus, .el-b-5:hover, .el-b-5:focus {
  background-color: #47cdff;
  margin-top: 8.5px;
  margin-bottom: 8.5px;
}
.el-b-1:active, .el-b-2:active, .el-b-3:active, .el-b-4:active, .el-b-5:active {
  background-color: #0b8aba;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to `.nav a` and remove `margin-top: 8.5px;`

Answer (score 0):

The fastest fix is the following code:

Add this to .css:

```
.nav li:hover{
    background:#47cdff;
    padding-top:7px;
    padding-bottom:31px;
}
```

Remove this from your css:

```
.el-b-1:hover, .el-b-1:focus, .el-b-2:hover, .el-b-2:focus, .el-b-3:hover, .el-b-3:focus,
.el-b-4:hover, .el-b-4:focus, .el-b-5:hover, .el-b-5:focus {
  background-color: #47cdff;
  margin-top: 8.5px;
  margin-bottom: 8.5px;
}
```

Sure, there are a lot of way to do this kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concept using `display: table` and `display: table-cell`.

- The nav is wrapped in a `<header>` with `display: table`
- The first link is removed from the nav, placed before it and given `display: table-cell` along with the nav. This ensures they both stay on the same line.
- The links in the nav are `display: inline-block` and are centered through the use of `line-height: 3em`. This line height controls the height of the entire header.
- When the screensize gets too small, the @media query CSS kicks in and the menu items are collapsed into a dropdown.
- When collapsed, `a.menu:hover + .menu-items` targets the menu-item div directly after the menu button.

### Demo

1. "Run code snippet" and open the demo full screen.
2. Shrink the width of the window and see the menu collapse into a dropdown.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  background-color: #00aeef;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  display: table;
}
.nav-hdr {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav {
  text-align: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 300px;
  /* Prevent shrinking too small */
  background-color: #00aeef;
}
.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  color: #FFF;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.nav a:last-child {
  padding-right: 1em;
  /* Last child gets a little extra padding on the right */
}
.nav a:hover,
.nav-hdr:hover {
  background-color: #0b8aba;
}
.nav a:active,
.nav-hdr:active {
  background-color: #47cdff;
}
/*Hide collapsed menu display link*/

a.menu {
  display: none;
}
/* When the screen size gets too small, collapse the links into a dropdown */

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .nav {
    min-width: 0;
    position: relative;
  }
  .nav .menu-items {
    display: none;
  }
  a.menu {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  a.menu:hover + .menu-items,
  .menu-items:hover {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3em;
    right: 0;
    background: #000;
  }
  .menu-items a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="" class="nav-hdr">Nigel Silva</a>
  <nav class="nav">
    <a class="menu">Menu (hover me)</a>

    <div class="menu-items">
      <a href="" class="el-b-1">Home</a><a href="" class="el-b-2">About</a><a href="" class="el-b-3">Work</a><a href="" class="el-b-4">Clients</a><a href="" class="el-b-5">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```